# Roo automatic delete _Roo_DbManaged.aj of DBRE Add-On

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-roo

My project use DBRE Add-On to reverse from database. After that, I run `roo` command and roo update the content of all .aj file. But roo delete the _Roo_DbManaged.aj so that my project can not work.  My question is how to prevent roo delete the  _Roo_DbManaged.aj .
Here is my  entityManagerFactory Beab
Thank for any help.

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/something"/>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml"/>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Roo doesn't uses the DB all the times (this could be too much expensive on system resource). So, DBRE command generates a file called `dbre.xml` which stores db schema info got from DB.

Check `dbre.xml` exists and hasn't been modified by anybody.

Good luck!